# Does the surface roughness play any role in shock absorbing?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, dynamics, shock, impact

Consider a mass of about $130 \pm 10 $ kg, falls from height, let say $2.5 $ m. 
In order to dampen the vibration and sound, I use silencer or drop pads. I was wondering if introducing the macroscopic projections, helps to reduce the thickness of the shock absorber in comparison to the classic flat surface shock absorbers. 
[image]

[image]

After reading Kamran's answer: 
I think the impact energy results in transversal deformation of the projected surface, that is in contrast to the vertical compression of the flat surface.  So there would be less energy transmitted to the floor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, look at it this way:

you are removing material that would otherwise help break the fall.

All it does is give the mass a chance to penetrate deeper into the drop pad.

It would be ok if you add it to existing pad for a thicker pad if you are looking for less noise and less stress to the floor.

Comment: Interesting, you mean the oneven surface helps to damp noises and the flat one damps the vibrations? If I'm right, then how does the combination look like? Series of pads on top of each other or maybe other configurations ?

Comment: Yes, possibly series like a sandwich.

Comment: I edited my question, could you please tell me if my theory is correct ?

Comment: @Sam Farjamirad, yes to some extend part of impact energy radiates out if you have layered structures. Eggshells layer could be crumple zone and solid layer could be shear and compression absorber.